# Pytorch: How to assign a default value for look-up table using torch tensor

Tags: pytorch

Say that I have two tensors as follows:

```
a = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
b = torch.tensor([0, 2, 3, 4])
```

where *b* is the lookup value for *a* such as:

```
b[a]
```

will return the value of:

```
tensor([[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]])
```

My problem is, what if I only have a look-up table of:

```
c = torch.tensor([0, 2, 3])
```

In which, for every out-of-index, I would like it to be assigned to index 0, such as *c[a]* will return

```
tensor([[2, 3, 0], [2, 3, 0]])
```

If I run *c[a]*, of course, I will get this result:

```
RuntimeError: index 3 is out of bounds for dim with size 3
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Code

```
# replace values greater than a certain number
def custom_replace(tensor, value, on_value):
    # we create a copy of the original tensor, 
    # because of the way we are replacing them.
    res = tensor.clone()
    res[tensor>=value] = on_value
    return res

a = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
c = torch.tensor([0, 2, 3])

a_ = custom_replace(a, c.size(0), 0)
print(c[a_])
```

> Output

```
tensor([[2, 3, 0],
        [2, 3, 0]])
```